# Adding google analytics to an android app

Tags: android, eclipse, google-analytics

I have a working android app and now want to add google analytics to it.  I am following the instructions here:

http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/

When I add the import statement:

```
import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;
```

I get the error:

```
The import com.google.android cannot be resolved
```

I have created a libs directory in the project and placed the libGoogleAnalytics.jar file in it.  I tried adding this to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.analytics" />
```

I have tried opening and closing Eclipse and doing 'Project / Clean'.  Nothing seems to affect the problem.  I am somewhat new to Java.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

I think you should add library libGoogleAnalytics.jar to build path (in libs right click on libGoogleAnalytics.jar -> BuildPAth -> Add to Build Path)
Do not add anything in Manifest file and in your java file use cmd+Shift+O(for Mac, for Windows Ctrl+Shift+O)  to automatically organize your imports)

Comment: You have to to one more think -> Open project properties ->Java build path ->Order and Export -> Check libGoogleAnalytics.jar